# How can i remove this line from visual studio

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio, ide, editor

[image]

How can I remove this yellow vertical line or change something else?
I am annoying of this.
Visual studio community 2019

Answer (score 0):

Disable **Track changes** in Text Editor options:

[image]